# Creating new class instances inside an array without overwriting existing ones

Tags: ruby, arrays, class, dictionary

I've currently got a system that involves quite a lot of new class instances, so I've had to assign them using an array, as was suggested here: [Create and initialize instances of a class with sequential names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578009/create-and-initialize-instances-of-a-class-with-sequential-names)

However, I'll have to be constantly adding new instances whenever a new one appears, without overwriting existing ones. Might some validation and a modified version of my existing code be the best option?

This is my code, currently every time it runs, the existing data is overwritten. I want the status to be overwritten if it's changed, but I also want to be able to store one or two variables in there permanently.

E2A: Ignore the global variables, they're just there for testing.

```
$allids = []
$position = 0 ## Set position for each iteration

    $ids.each do |x| ## For each ID, do
        $allids = ($ids.length).times.collect { MyClass.new(x)} ## For each ID, make a new class instance, as part of an array

        $browser.goto("http://www.foo.com/#{x}") ## Visit next details page

        thestatus = Nokogiri::HTML.parse($browser.html).at_xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/b/text()").to_s ## Grab the ID's status

        theamount = Nokogiri::HTML.parse($browser.html).at_xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/p[1]/b[2]/text()").to_s ## Grab a number attached to the ID

        $allids[$position].getdetails(thestatus, theamount) ## Passes the status to getdetails

        $position += 1 ## increment position for next iteration
    end
```

E2A2: Gonna paste this from my comment:

Hmm, I was just thinking, I started off by making the previous values dump into another variable, then another variable grabs the new values, and iterates over them to see if any match the previous values. That's quite a messy way to do it though, I was thinking, would self.create with a ||= work? – Joe 7 mins ago

Comment: Could you exactly say which data and in which variable you want to store permanently, please?

Comment: Sure, thanks very much for the response :) The data that should be kept (at least for a little bit) would be thestatus , and the outside variables that will be stored in there permanently will be called progress and messagecount .

Comment: Hmm, I was just thinking, I started off by making the previous values dump into another variable, then another variable grabs the new values, and iterates over them to see if any match the previous values. That's quite a messy way to do it though, I was thinking, would self.create with a ||= work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to store status and amount for each ID, right? If so, then something like this would help you:

```
# I'll store nested hash with class instance, status and amount for each id in processed_ids var
$processed_ids = {}

$ids.each do |id|
  processed_ids[id] ||= {} #
  processed_ids[id][:instance] ||= MyClass.new(id)
  processed_ids[id][:status] = get_status # Nokogiri method
  processed_ids[id][:amount] = get_amount # Nokogiri method
end
```

What does this code do: it only once creates instance of your class for each id, but always updates its status and amount.

Comment: You know, I really really love it when people explains why the code works, not just what code works. Thanks so so much! :)